# KVM VIrtual Network only allow ports 22

Tags: iptables, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have a KVM host with some VMs
The Host has a SMB Share in it

All the guest VMs need to connect to this SMB FileShare
And i need it to be via virtual network
(preverably KVM's 'default' virtual network)

Unfortunately it does not work,

==> Guest vm can not connect to port 445

==> Guest VM does connect to host on port 22

So... it seems to be firewall related

I installed on the host GUFW tool

And even if i leave everything opened on GUFW,

guest vm still can not connect to port 445 or other ports, except for port 22

This is the virtual network config via the "**virsh net-edit default**" command:

```
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>79ee9f24-786a-4318-87d9-3b48bcdf1741</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'/>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:66:67:6a'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.51' end='192.168.122.99'/>
      <host mac='52:54:00:dc:23:9f' name='zabbix' ip='192.168.122.131'/>
      <host mac='52:54:00:49:fe:47' name='LAB_SFBSE' 
ip='192.168.122.126'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

The test i am making is a simple telnet command

I have tried on the guest running the telnet against:
The IP of the default gateway of virbr0: telnet 192.168.122.1 445
The IP of the Host NIC: telnet 192.168.15.199 445

I managed to get this working via Bridged networking
But when i attach the guest VM to the default NAT Network it can only connect to port 22

i have tested this on multiple hosts and multiple installations
the behavior is always the same

Any sugestions on how can i get this working?

Comment: What Linux is it? Some distros will allow easy configuration of iptables through the `firewall-cmd` command. Example: `firewall-cmd --add-service=samba --permanent; firewall-cmd --reload`

Comment: It's not necessarily firewall related. Have you verified that the smb service is listening on the address(es) you think it is (using, e.g., `netstat -tln`)?

Comment: Output of netstat:

# netstat -tln |grep 445
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN

Comment: firewall-cmd --add-service=samba

This command does it
I tried adding samba rules using GUFW but it did not work
your command did the trick thanks Havenard